# Python function that is supposed to return the nth Fibonacci number, but it's returning the wrong value for certain inputs

Tags: python, function, fibonacci

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

print(fibonacci(5)) # should return 3
```

have a Python function that is supposed to return the nth Fibonacci number, but it's returning the wrong value for certain inputs.

Comment: @Axe319 0 is the first Fibonacci number

Comment: The sequence you are generating is 0-indexed, so the 0th Fibonacci number is 0, the 1st is 1, the 2nd is 1, the 3rd is 2, the 4th is 3, the 5th is 5, etc.

Comment: If you want it to be 1-indexed, then change the base cases so that `n<=1` returns 0 and  `n == 2` returns 1. (`fibonacci(0)` would still return 0 as well, but it should essentially be considered undefined.)

Comment: @chepner The Fibonacci sequence *can* start at 1. However, in modern usage it's generally accepted that it should start at 0. Therefore the 5th number in the sequence is indeed 3 (0, 1, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: @Pingu I'm talking about the indices used to *refer* to the numbers in the sequence, not starting the sequence with 1. That is, if this were a list, it would be `[None, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...]`, rather than `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a generator that is designed to return up n Fibonacci numbers. Out of that, create a list and print the last item in that list.

For example:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print(list(fibonacci(5))[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
3
```

**Note:**

I only suggest this way as I already had the generator coded. Perhaps better would be:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for _ in range(n-1):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

print(fibonacci(5))
```